# jQuery FullCalendar, view month one more week is showing up

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the plug in FullCalendar in a month view (default one),

And when the month is printed it's showing one more week each time.

Let me know if you want more details or screenshots

```
    $('#calendar_expanded').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: "month",
        firstDay: $('#inputUserStartWeek').val(),
        height: $(window).height()-100
    });
```

[image: fullCalendar]

Comment: We want more details and screen shots.  Plus your code and maybe a jsFiddle.

Comment: ok it's edited, i think you got all the info ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting weekMode to liquid or variable:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/weekMode/

Comment: liquid worked, thank you. It was fast. Have a good day!